# Dependencies are incompatible with updated loopback-cli version

Tags: npm, npm-install, loopback4

I have just Updated @loopback/cli version from 1.21.4 to 1.24.0. But now some dependencies are incompatible with the updated loopback version. For every command with lb4, it is giving the following error

> The project was originally generated by @loopback/cli@1.21.4. The
>   following dependencies are incompatible with @loopback/cli@1.24.0:
>   - typescript: ~3.5.3 (cli ~3.6.4) ? Continue to run the command? No Generation is aborted: Error: Incompatible dependencies

I also tried npm update But it didn't solve the problem.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This command solved the problem. You have to update typescript and save in package.json

```
npm install typescript@3.6.4 --save
```